# Playing .vob files on Linux

Tags: video

Having trouble playing DVDs on my laptop. They are .vob files. Neither VLC, Mplayer nor SMPlayer seem to help. Anything else I could do?

Comment: Do you have libdvdcss installed? If not, you can't play DVDs.